# How to distribute a Drupal website on a flash card?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to take a Drupal website and distribute the information on it on a flash card or DVD -- even if it is a read only version. The people who will be using the website will not always have internet access. Plus, it's the type of information that somebody would like to sponsor. So at intervals the website will be published onto a flash card or DVD with a company logo on it and the website will be branded to the company. Any ideas?

Comment: I take you are asking how to make a Drupal site a static site that you can then distribute on a support.

Answer (score 7):

You can run a dynamic, database-driven Drupal site from a DVD or Flash memory stick using a system like [portable XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp), which is designed to run on removable drives, and includes Apache, PHP and MySQL.

If you only need static pages, you can use the [HTML Export module](http://drupal.org/project/html_export), which will export all your image, JavaScript and CSS, and export your nodes as HTML pages. I've tried it and it works as advertised.

Comment: I personnaly like [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/), also don't forget that using this very often can reduce the life of your flash card due to the number of writes that generates a LAMP stack.